# Перейти на страницу по кнопке и разрегистрировать переменную сессии?

Tags: php

В общем, нужно по клику на кнопке перейти по адресу,
передать скрытое значение
и сделать unset переменной.

Comment: И с чем у вас проблемы?

Comment: > В общем нужно по клику на кнопке ...

Эх, раз нужно, то нужно. Что ж тут поделать? Уговорили, делайте.

Comment: На каком этапе сложности?

Comment: @anunak, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот форма:

```
<form action="url">
<input type="hidden" value="test" name="hidval">
<input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
</form>
```

Обработка:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
//сброс
    unset($var);
}

?>
```

Comment: ой, я и сам так сделал. Честно-честно. Просто на сайт не заходил.